# Unexplained Bluetooth notification upon disconnecting

Tags: notifications, bluetooth

Pixel 6a, Android 13 (July update) was connected to Jabra Elite 65T and I experienced this weird and inexplicable notification

- On disconnecting the BT, this notification appeared:

[image]

- On tapping it, it turns out to be the previously paired Jabra but showing it as **unknown**.

[image]

- This was very strange because:

  - Jabra BT was given the permissions the first time it was paired and never asked for them ever. I've been getting calls with contact names read out too.
  - I didn't receive/approve any other BT paring request ever.
  - This notification appeared only *after* disconnecting and not on connecting

    - Just to rule out the unlikely event of another BT device possibly somehow getting connected,and asking for phone book access, I again connected & disconnected to see the notification yet again. This has **never** happened in the past AFAIK. Also in BT connections no other device was showing up

I am trying to understand why this happened but can't think of any reason neither does a Google search help.

Can someone please explain how the Jabra device shows up as "unknown" and ask for previously approved phone book access?

Comment: You need to do some more tests